# Boot choice not appearing after Ubuntu 22.10 installation alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10, 22.10

it's been two days that I'm stuck on a Ubuntu 22.10 installation on a laptop alongside Windows 10.

My Laptop is an Acer Spin5 and has 32GB of free unallocated space in the SSD
Secure Boot is disabled
The Ubuntu Installation has been downloaded from the official Ubuntu website and burned into an USB Stick
The Disc Image worked perfectly on another laptop (a Lenovo)
Problem is: no matter what I do, the Boot partition with the biosgrub does not appear in the BIOS list. I've tried both automatic "Install alongside Windows 10" and (a bunch of times the) manual "Something else" options in the Ubuntu "Installation Type" screen.

When "Something else", I've tried to assign the "Device for boot loader installation" first to the "Windows Boot Manager" partition, then to the /dev/sda and, given neither of those have worked, then to a new partition created from the free unallocated space as EFI.

The installation seems to go well, no error in any case is returned, but when I restart the system, no matter what, Windows kicks in and checking the Bios Boot Menu, no item Ubuntu or biosgrub or other related is added to the boot list.

***UPDATE***
I've downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 in order to run boot-repair from the live Ubuntu. Still no result.

As asked by Paul Benson, here's the output of the command `sudo parted -l`

```
Model: ATA HFS128G39TND-N21 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Warning: failed to translate partition name
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      106MB   123MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      123MB   91.8GB  91.7GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      91.8GB  127GB   35.1GB  ext4
 4      127GB   128GB   1074MB  ntfs                                       hidden, diag
```

Comment: From Live Ubuntu, run *sudo parted -l* and paste output into question.

Comment: Hi @PaulBenson, just pasted what you asked into the question. Appreciate any help you can give me, thanks, man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your partitions look ok. Now there is a specific issue with some Acer models, eg Aspires re dual booting Windows and Linux. I'm not an expert on Acer machines (I've never owned one) but I know a few things about them.

The first thing you must do is enter UEFI (tapping F2 key as soon as Acer logo appears on booting up). Hit the Security tab and set a Supervisor Password. Then disable Secure Boot.

Then you need to select a 'UEFI file to trust'. You'll see that option on the same page. This means adding the file - *grubx64.efi*. This file should be present on the path - */EFI/ubuntu/grubx.64.efi* on your hard drive, but *grubx64.efi* may be sufficient rather than quoting its actual path - I'm not sure about that. It could even be -  *\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi*, using Windows notation. In fact I'd be inclined to try that one first as UEFI firmware is built to be used for Windows . Whatever, it's important to get it right.

When you've done all that save settings and reboot back to UEFI, go to the Boot tab, and make sure that **ubuntu** is set to first boot. Save settings again, and reboot. With a bit of luck that should now take you to the grub menu.

**Edit**: We don't know yet whether Ubuntu's efi boot file is present in the sda1 partition, although it should be after a Linux installation. Ideally you should check this first from Live Ubuntu before you do any of the above to be sure. First, from the terminal mount sda1: **sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt**, then **ls /mnt/EFI/ubuntu**. *Grubx64.efi* should show as present as well as *shimx64.efi*. The latter needs to be trusted if Secure Boot is enabled. Then unmount sda1: **sudo umount /dev/sda1**.

Comment: FIrst of all, let me thank you, @PaulBenson, as I'm replying to your answer from Firefox preinstalled browser in the Ubuntu distro. It worked and actually's been pretty easy to follow your instructions. 
Sorry I can't cast a vote, but apparently I'm a newbie here and they won't let me.

Comment: @SteveRoss You're welcome. If you want to theme you're grub menu and make it look a lot more appealing than the raw-looking black background with a few white menu options, eg. [such as this](https://imgur.com/a/n2sSihm), please let us know.